# iterate over a len of list in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2

I've a context variable:

```
"images": [
        {
            "date": "2015-06-02T11:51:53Z",
            "image": "auction/Screenshot_from_2015-05-18_235741.png",
            "auction_id": 1,
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "date": "2015-06-23T09:38:45Z",
            "image": "auction/Screenshot_from_2015-06-22_203407.png",
            "auction_id": 1,
            "id": 2
        },
        .....
    ],
```

I want to loop over this list of dictionary in the following way

```
{% for image in images %}
    <a class="thumb-item-link" data-slide-index="{{over here should be the index of the current iteration}}" href=""><img src="/media/{{image.image}}" alt="img"/></a> 
{% endfor %}
```

For eg :-

```
<a class="thumb-item-link" data-slide-index="0" href=""><img src="/media/auction/Screenshot_from_2015-05-18_235741.png" alt="img"/></a> 

<a class="thumb-item-link" data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="/media/auction/Screenshot_from_2015-06-22_203407.png" alt="img"/></a> 

<a class="thumb-item-link" data-slide-index="2" href=""><img src="/media/auction/Screenshot_from_2015-06-22_203488.png" alt="img"/></a>
```

Over here `data-slide-index` is changing its value as per the current iteration. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use from this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#for):

```
{{forloop.counter0}}
```

and django in each loop will enumerate indexes from 0.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you :)

Comment: @user1162512 should probably then mark the answer as final